# Calling function from a module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am working on a python script to call a variable from a file from another file.It is an IAM policy for an IAM user. I have a function calling variables in another file
file with the function is named "template_utils.py". I want the output in JSON format. I am not sure what is the problem.

```
import sys
import json
import time 
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
def create_aws_iam_policy_template(**kwargs):
  template_data = {}
  template_data["region"] = kwargs.get('region')
  template_data["instance_types"] = kwargs.get('instance_type')
  template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = kwargs.get('ebs_volume_size')
  template_data["meta_template_name"] = kwargs.get('meta_template_name')

  meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
  meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
  template_json = meta_template_json.format(template_data)
  return template_json  

template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
  region="us-east2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size=20,
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template"
)
```

print(template_json)

This is the file with policy called "meta_template.py"

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template
ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
tm = Template(json.dumps(ec2_policy_meta_template))
parsed_policy = tm.render(region='us-east-1', ebs_volume_size='12', instance_type='t2.micro')
print(parsed_policy)
```

This is the error I am getting when running "template_utils.py"

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Sid": "VisualEditor0", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "ec2:RunInstances", "Resource": ["arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::instance/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::network-interface/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::key-pair/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::security-group/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::subnet/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::volume/*", "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"], "Condition": {"ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {"ec2:VolumeSize": "12"}, "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"}}}, {"Sid": "VisualEditor1", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["ec2:TerminateInstances", "ec2:StartInstances", "ec2:StopInstances"], "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::instance/*", "Condition": {"ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"}}}, {"Sid": "VisualEditor2", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["ec2:Describe*", "ec2:GetConsole*", "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms", "iam:ListInstanceProfiles", "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics", "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs", "ec2:CreateKeyPair"], "Resource": "*", "Condition": {"DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": ""}, "DateLessThanEquals": {"aws:CurrentTime": ""}}}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pranay/Desktop/work/template_utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
  File "/home/pranay/Desktop/work/template_utils.py", line 15, in create_aws_iam_policy_template
    template_json = meta_template_json.format(template_data)
KeyError: '"Version"'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use strings in `meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template"` if you could access directly data `meta_template_name=meta_template.ec2_policy_meta_template`

Comment: you use `JSON` to convert `ec2_policy_meta_template` to string and later you use it with `format()` - BUT `format()` uses `{ }` to recognize variables and you have JSON string with `{"VERSION"...` and `format()` thinks it is variable which it has to replace. And you have more `{` and `}` which it will tread like places to replace values. You would have to use `{{ }}` to keep them as normal `{ }`.

Comment: I see also you use `{{region}}` to put some values but `format()` will not put it because it treads `{{` and `}}` as nomal string. It would have to be `{region}`. It seem like you mix `format()` with `jinja2` which use `{{ }}` to place elements in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all your problem is you mix two differen methods to fill templates - `text.format()` and `jinja2`

`text.format()` uses

- `{variable}` to put value in template
- `{{ }}` to keep it as normal `{ }`

`jinja2` uses

- `{{variable}}` to put value in template
- `{ }` to keep it as normal `{ }`

And you have `{{region}}` to put value so you exepect `jinj2` method but you use `format()` which uses other method and it sees `{"VERSION"...` in your template and it tries to replace it.

You have to use `jinja2` - it will be simpler then changing template for `format()`

---

`string formatting`

```
'{"VERSION": "{{region}}" }'.format(region="us-east2")
```

result:

```
KeyError: '"VERSION"'
```

---

`jinja2`

```
from jinja2 import Template

t = Template('{"VERSION": "{{region}}" }')
t.render(region="us-east2")
```

result:

```
'{"VERSION": "us-east2" }'
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you still don't understand it.

`jinja2` is not function of `string` but external module which you have to install

```
 pip install Jinja2
```

and import and use it in special way.

For your example it can be something like this

```
from jinja2 import Template

template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)
```

It uses placeholders with double `{{` and `}}` - like in your template `{{region}}`. And it doesn't try to replace value when you have single `{` `}` like in `'{"VERSION": ...}`. So it will works with your template in correct way.

But original `format()` works in different way - it uses placeholders with single `{` and `}` - so it thing that you have placeholder `'{"VERSION": ...}` and it can't find variable `"VERSION"` in `template_data` to replace it. And it makes problem.

Comment: I don't want '{"VERSION": "us-east2" }', I just want to fill in the placeholders. Rest will remain the same I have made some changes in the code according to your suggestion but I am still not sure what should I use instead of .format() in my function. I have made the changes in the question as well.It does the job and gives the desired outcome but with an error. TIA.

Comment: if you want to use `{{ region }}` then DONT use `format` but `jinja2` - you use wrong function for `{{ region }}`. And if you still want to use `format()` then you have to `{ region }` with single `{` and `}` instead of double `{{` and `}}`. BUT then you will have to replace all original `{` `}` to `{{`, `}}`

Comment: It throws the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'jinja2' for the line "  template_json = meta_template_json.jinja2(template_data)"

Comment: DID you see my answer - `jinja2` is NOT funciton of string but EXTERNAL module. You CAN"T use it as `meta_template_json.jinja2(template_data)"` You have to `import jinja2` and `text = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)`

Comment: I added example exactly with your variables.